# Indian Liver Dataset 1 Dimensional Convolutional Neural Network Problem

Tags: python

I am new at this deep learning thing and i tried to perform 1D CNN for Indian Liver Dataset.
I wrote some codes on Spyder and got error with data shape. I dont know how to solve. Can you guys please help me?
Here is my code and the data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/burak/Masaüstü/liverdata.csv")

X = data.drop(["Gender","Dataset"], axis=1)
y = data["Dataset"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling1D
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(408,9)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=15)
```

And got this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_28_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (408, 9)

And here is the data
https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/indian-liver-patient-records

Comment: try (None, 3), but i think what ever you are writing doesn't make any sence. unless your data is time series, or images, or the sequential data of a single entity, conv1d wont work. please learn the concepts before you apply.

Comment: Conv1D expects 3-dimensional input: n_samples * depth * n_features. Here, depth is, for example, the time component; so data[0, 2, 1] would be the second feature of the first sample at the third "time step". When skimming the dataset it didn't seem to me that applying a convolution is the right thing to do here (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Answer (score 0):

You should make up your mind about how you preprocess the data from your .csv (normalization, Input shape, etc.), as of right now, your `Conv1D` expects a certain input shape, which are not complying with. Try adjusting your data input or changing your network.
Also, just because a line of code in your network does not produce an error does not mean, that it will contribute to the result you expect. The structure of your network highly depends on the task at hand, there are pretty much no universal approaches.